# Self-referencing loop error

Tags: json, vb.net, self-reference

I have a self referencing loop. I tried reading and implementing some of the other answers but it does not seem to work. I have a class that saves my object as a json file (method). It attempts to serialize the object but throws an exception for a self-referencing loop. The object I am serializing is the second block (class). How can I fix the issue? It did work until I added buttons, so I am assuming I am doing something wrong with handlers, but I really have no idea.

```
  Public Sub saveLocalSettings()
        Console.WriteLine("saveLocalSettings")
        If Not Directory.Exists(_SettingsFile) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(_SettingsFile)
        End If
        '  Try
        Dim strConfigurationManager As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_LocalSettings, PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects)
        'Dim strConfigurationManager As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_LocalSettings, Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore)
        lm.writeFile(_SettingsFile + _FileName, strConfigurationManager, True)
        '  Catch ex As Exception
        ' End Try
    End Sub

Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Public Class RGOSetting
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property title As String
    Private mtbTitle As New MaskedTextBox
    Public Property sharestatus As Integer
    Public Property settingstring As String
    Public Property userid As Integer
    Public Property setting_profiles As New List(Of RGOSettingProfile)
    Private rgolcm As RGOLeagueChampionManager
    '  Private rgolssm As RGOLeagueSumSpManager
    Public btnUpdate As New Button
    Public btnReset As New Button
    Public btnClear As New Button
    End Class

Public Class RGOSettingProfile
    Public Property champion As LeagueChampion
    Public Property summoner_spells As New List(Of LeagueSummonerSpell)

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal strChampion As String, ByVal strSummonerSpell As List(Of String))
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You cant serialize controls (at least not that way) so it is not clear why they are there. Is `_LocalSettings` an instance of  `RGOSetting`?  What is `RGOSettingProfile`?  Are you trying to do something like profiles (multiple named config sets)?

Comment: Yes, I have multiple settings with multiple settings. The controls are dynamically added to a panel and I need to add a handler to save it. I have the image here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-0AOVbB5W589j52-LEN1wRat80jPrLTmCjtoOj0u7Pc/edit?usp=sharing. I still have to add the second part where each champion produces another icon panel where you can select / deselect objects. You can select any of the champions and each champion has a list of the same option. I also added RGOSettingProfile

Comment: If there are 3 buttons associated with each thing, they dont need to be dynamic - given the names they all do the same thing in each case.  Detach the UI stuff from the user data (something in the data might map tho them like some text or an image though).  One way to link the data to the Ui would be to create a usercontrol.  When passed one of those objects it displays the data accordingly.

Comment: So the buttons are causing the error? I thought they had to be a property to be serialized. Is there another way to fix the issue? I'll have to look into user controls, I just like making my own objects and stuff.

Comment: I don't want to serialize the buttons anyway, maybe I will just make them private and use a public method to set the handler.

Comment: I dint know whats causing it - there is still lots of missing types in the post.  I do know its a bad idea to comingle user data (like a profile/settings collection) with UI controls)...and UserControls *are* 'your own stuff'.  It would be like a mini form with all the required controls on it - create an interface to feed it a profile object and add code to have it populate the display.  The handlers would already be there and wired up (just like in a form)

Comment: I wish I was smart enough to understand lol. I have not used user controls yet and will have to study it. I already created the champion objects and they return the icons you can see in the image. I have a border handler to select them and just have to create the second panel that has a list of options for each champion and I have a class that can create the panel which is identical to the champions which is one of the reasons I created them dynamically. Plus I have to track the selections they make and then save them to a file I use later.

Comment: I took two semesters of vb. Net, guess I did not learn enough lol

Comment: The self referencing error means that somewhere in the graph (objectA.objectB.objectC ...) something refers to itself or a class which in turn refers to it.  `LeagueChampion` (one of the types not shown) for instancve would seem to be redundant with some data in `RGOSetting`

Comment: How do I make values that don't serialize? It seems much easier to use the champion manager for the controls and then create a list based on the choices and serialize the list... Or am I still doing it wrong? I'm almost done with school and feel clueless lol. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this with the buttons and it allowed me to save the objects:

```
<JsonIgnore> Public btnUpdate As New Button
<JsonIgnore> Public btnReset As New Button
<JsonIgnore> Public btnClear As New Button
```